# Keeping a component in front of a movie clip - Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have a combo box that is used to load movie clips from the library.  The problem is, the movie clips have a white background so they cover the combo box when the are added to the stage.  How do I keep the combo box in front of the movie clips?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
import fl.controls.ComboBox;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.display.*;
//import flash.net.navigateToURL; 
var helpItems:Array = new Array( 
    {label:"Overview", data:"p1"}, 
    {label:"Operation", data:"p2"}, 
    {label:"Component Menu",  data:"p3"}, 
    {label:"Buttons",  data:"p4"}, 
    {label:"Meter Function", data:"p5"}, 
    {label:"Pull Down Menus", data:"p6"}, 
    {label:"Browse and Navigation", data:"p7"} 
);

var myCB:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
myCB.dropdownWidth = 150;
myCB.width = 130;
myCB.move(1.35, 1.35);
myCB.prompt = "Select a Menu Item";
myCB.dataProvider = new DataProvider(helpItems);
myCB.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

addChild(myCB);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var libraryItem:Class = getDefinitionByName(String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data)) as Class;
    var helpMov:MovieClip = new libraryItem() as MovieClip;
    helpMov.name = String(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data);
    trace(ComboBox(event.target).selectedItem.data);
    helpMov.x = 0;
    helpMov.y = 0;
    addChild(helpMov);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use method 
`addChildAt(helpMov, this.numChildren - 2)` 
instead of `addChild(helpMov)`.

In `addChildAt()` method you get current number of child movie clips that are in current movieclip with property `numChildren` that return number of all child movie clips. In movie clips child clips are layed by their index (beginning with `0`). Movie clip with the highest index is on top of others. When you add children with method `addChild()`, Flash takes +1 then biggest current index. So if you want to keep your combo box always on top you have to always give new to new children a lower index. Biggest index is always `numChildren - 1`.